# how to take youtube embedded code as input from user and echo in php

Tags: php, html

I've created a form that user can input youtube embedded code, so that it can display on website:

```
<form action="postvideo.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="videocode"></textarea>
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="postvideo" value="Publish Video">
</form>
```

And I wanted to echo through php:

```
<?php
    echo $val=$_POST['videocode'];
?>
```

But its not working...

Comment: its work perfectly, do you print  **$val** in postvideo.php page?

Comment: yes I printed it..and also tried print_r($_POST) but its not passing the textarea value..

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, so the problem is very, very unlikely to be related to your code. Most likely you have not got PHP properly configured. After you submit the form, View Source in the browser. Do you see the PHP source code? Do you see the submitted code? (That might simply be wrong)

Answer (score -2):

Try Using this

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");

If you get the data . The reason for empty $_POST is mod_security

Comment: the output is something like this : videocode=%3Ciframe+width%3D%22560%22+height%3D%22315%22+src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fembed%2FuCMxYKTCUE0%22+frameborder%3D%220%22+allowfullscreen%3E%3C%2Fiframe%3E&postvideo=Publish+Video

Comment: try disabling the mod_security module